# Algorithm to find a node with particular properties in a tree given a starting node and the approximate path

Tags: html, algorithm, dom, graph, graph-algorithm

I am looking for a logic which predicts where a particular element lies in the DOM of a specific page, given that we know some general properties of the element, and the approximate path from a few fixed nodes in the template to the element (obtained by analyzing a few pages of the similar type).

**Specific Example:**

There are a few Wikipedia pages to be analyzed:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Econometrics

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_economic_thought

etc
.
.
.

The algorithm must get the right navigation box (`class="vertical-navbox nowraplinks plainlist"`) in these pages, given the following conditions:

1. The class name of the element might not be same in all the pages
2. The path to the navbox from the header (`id="firstHeading"`), and some other fixed nodes, in a few pages(test cases) is available
3. The header(and the other fixed nodes) always has the same id in each page
4. Some pages might have a few extra nodes in the path (`class="hatnote"` in the second link)
5. A few properties of the box(it is in blue color, it is a table etc..) are known

Is there an algorithm for this purpose?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. Do you want an heuristic able to predict with some degree of success the position of the node without vising the dom tree? Or do you want to optimize the speed of the tree search? Or something else altogether?

Comment: I'm after the first case. To be precise, the algorithm is to be trained on a few pages, then, it is expected to get the required nodes in other pages autonomously, with some degree of success.

Comment: I really don't see how you could accomplish this: BGP predicts path length by means of connection speed information between peers that the peer calculates through pings (keep-alive messages). But that means that some kind of global tree traversal happens anyway. The only way in your case would be if the test cases could somehow be predictive of your actual page but IMHO it's either trivial or quite difficult.

Comment: _The Wikipedia pages are for illustration purposes only, the content in those have no connection with the problem_

.Coming back to the problem, since all the pages are from Wikipedia, it can be assumed that they would be somewhat similar in their structure, albeit some extra boxes popping in middle of the path in a few pages. But these extra nodes generally are in small numbers. So, the algorithm should find the node, with a certain confidence associated with it that the node is the required target.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's make some assumption and see if they are compatible with your situation.

Let's say you have a test page and in that test page you can do complete dom tree visits.

In this case we could do a series of reversal path walks, from every leaf to the root, assuming a node has a score of 0 at the beginning and adding +1 if the branch from where we came up contained the wanted node.

After we have done this for all possible paths from leafs to root, we do another full visit and we divide the previously calculated score by the number of children (sub-trees or leaves) each node has.

This means that for every node now you have a percentage telling you the probability of a random sub-tree of that node containing the desired nodes.

Now, for the prediction part, you need some way to match a node in another page to one of the nodes for which you have probabilities (and for this I'm afraid I don't have any idea how it could be done).

Once you have such a match, and assuming the test page is really predictive, you have automatically a probability factor for each node of the new page that should be meaningful, notwithstanding any possible intermediate additional node.

Note that with the matching algorithm you could do the same calculation for multiple test pages and at the end of each process calculate an overall probability for each node that, hopefully, is more precise than your original one.

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: This looks good, but it would only be half of the solution. This would give a probability-scored set of nodes. I think it would not be very productive just following the probabilities, as it would result in many node visits. Is there a any algorithm to traverse this tree? I'm thinking of any methods like Ant Colony, or Artificial Bee Colony algorithms which show an efficient way of how to traverse a graph.

Comment: The traversal algorithm strongly depends on the use you want to do of the data afterwards, for example it could be handy to prepare an associative table with every node while calculating the probabilities. Or you could prepare other different data structures to expedite graph traversal. The algorithms that you mention are nice but they cover the discover and the traversal of previously unknown graphs, while in your case you already have some partial information on the new page so the optimizations of these algorithms is somewhat diluted.